# Tesseract "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. Data path must contain subfolder tessdata"

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to use the tesseract libray for java in my Android application as suggested here: http://vkedco.blogspot.com/2013/03/vladimir-kulyukin-learning-objectives-1.html

I have followed the instructions as it is and I still get an error that says that I need to have the subfolder tessdata in the path. The subfolder does exist in my sdcard/tesseract_languages folder.

Any suggestions about what I should do to get this running?

Error details are given below:

```
05-13 20:54:35.653: E/AndroidRuntime(11715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 20:54:35.653: E/AndroidRuntime(11715): Process: com.example.msapp2, PID: 11715
05-13 20:54:35.653: E/AndroidRuntime(11715): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.msapp2/com.example.msapp2.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!
05-13 20:54:35.653: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-13 20:54:35.653: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-13 20:54:35.653: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-13 20:54:35.653: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
```

Comment: Did you get any solution on this?

Comment: We have to maintain folder structure according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33969403/3142611). Don't forget to maintain language file inside of this folder

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue. When reading the source code, I found:

```
public boolean init(String datapath, String language) {
        if (datapath == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data path must not be null!");
        if (!datapath.endsWith(File.separator))
            datapath += File.separator;

        File tessdata = new File(datapath + "tessdata");
        if (!tessdata.exists() || !tessdata.isDirectory())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!");

        return nativeInit(datapath, language);
    }
```

which means don't add "tessdata" to the datapath. The method init() will add it.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I've also read sources and I have omitted this detail.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Worked for me when I removed "tessdata" from the path, as yushlx answer.

Before (fail):
path = "/mnt/sdcard/tesseract/tessdata";
After (success):
path = "/mnt/sdcard/tesseract/";

Of course, tessdata folder should be in the path with the desired.traineddata file.