# How to get the directory that needs to be used in tessbase.init("directory", "eng")?

Tags: java, android, ocr, tesseract

So I am trying to figure out how to use TessBase, and I get an error at `baseApi.init(dataPath, "eng")`. The error I get is : `directory must contain tessdata`. I can't figure out how to get the directory that contains tessdata. This is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dKTw.jpg) of the directory that contains eng.traineddata. This is my code:

```
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap photoBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    //textcaptured.setText(DATA_PATH.toString());/*
    String dataPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +  "/";
    textcaptured.setText(dataPath);
    File tessdata = new File(dataPath);
    if (!tessdata.exists() || !tessdata.isDirectory()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!");
    }
    baseApi.init(dataPath, "eng");
    baseApi.setImage(photoBitmap);
    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text(); // Log or otherwise display this string...
    baseApi.end();
    textcaptured.setText(recognizedText);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **easiest** way that I recommend is to 
make a folder in your sdcard by yourself and put a directory with subdirectory tessdata with eng.tessdata in it the structure shown here:

```
+SdCardOfPhone
--+YourAppName
----+tessdata
------eng.tessdata
```

now you can point to that directory by

```
    String datapath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/YourAppName/";        
    TessBaseAPI tessBaseAPI = new TessBaseAPI();        
    tessBaseAPI.init(datapath, "eng");
```

you also have to have the following in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For testing purposes I don't recommend bundling your eng.tessdata inside the project it increases the build time and the size of your .apk file(>17mb).

The process of bundling eng.tessdata inside the project is quite involved and involves making a new directory by yourself and copying the bundled data to that directory in runtime.